# Hostname from Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server

Tags: java, java-8, redhat

I am using given below java code to get the Hostname from RHEL Using IBM JDK 1.8

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
public class Hostname {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
             String hostname  = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
             System.out.println("Hostname is :"+hostname);
            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" Exception  :"+e);
            System.out.println(" Exception Msg :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

1. Hostname from RHEL 6.9 /IBM JDK 1.8 = `vas2cxn00001122`.
2. Fully qualified hostname from RHEL 7.6 / IBM JDK 1.8 = `vas2cxn00003344.cloud.vd.org`.

Why is there a difference between 6.9 vs 7.6?  Where we have to update or modify the hostname in RHEL 7.6, in order to get only hostname, instead of fully qualified hostname.

Comment: its was fixed in jdk 7u5  its seems  based on the given below link. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7166687

Comment: sounds like an answer to me.  Why not post it as such?

Comment: thats my bad . java code is fixed as per the link, but i am getting fully qualified name in RHEL 7.6 .

Comment: Again, you asked a good question and then you found a valuable answer.  It may seem like a link-only answer, but I don't think it is.  The answer is "This is a bug that was fixed in version XXX" and then the link just backs that up.  What I'm recommending is that you post that as an answer to your own question so that you get some rep and so that the question has a valid answer.  I'll upvote your answer if you post it.

Comment: As per java link, which is i mention it - its fixed in jdk 7 version itself.
But i am facing this issue ie fully qualified name from hostname(),
is there anything i have to check from RHEL 7.6 OS level?

Comment: Ah...I misunderstood you.  So sorry.  So you're saying that it SHOULD be fixed for you, but even though you're using JDK 1.8 and this was fixed in 1.7, you're still getting the fully qualified hostname.  Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I could not able to find out the root cause of RHEL 7.6 . So i have changed my java logic

```
from 

InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()

to 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hostname")
```